# in Typescript, try...catch error object shows "Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)"

Tags: node.js, typescript

```js
router.get('/cells', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const result = await fs.readFile(fullPath, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
      res.send(JSON.parse(result));
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.code === 'ENOENT') { // Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571) (local var) err: unknown
        await fs.writeFile(fullPath, '[]', 'utf-8');
        res.send([]);
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
```

`err.code` make this ts error : `Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)`

I definitely know that `err.code` exists, so I want to know how to define the type(or interface) of `err`?

(tsc version info : My global typescript version is **v4.3.5** and the above code belongs to my project which has typescript **v4.1.2**)

--- Edit ---

I finally know why this error happens to me.
I thought I used tsc version under 4.3.x, but it turns out I used v4.4.x.

In vscode, `cmd + shift + P` and search for Select Typescript version
and I actually used v4.4.3, (I mistakenly thought on version because I only check tsc version from terminal)

[image]

[image]

Thanks for sharing [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyBvFey7pVc),

Comment: Its a recent change with TypeScript 4.4 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyBvFey7pVc 

Comment: @basarat Thank you, now I finally figure out what was wrong with me, It turns out that I used typescript version 4.4.x in vscode

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just very recently, Typescript has been update to make error object inside `catch` be `unknown` instead of `any`

which means, your code looks something like this to your compiler

```
catch(e: unknown) {
// your logic
}
```

Provide your own interface and save into another variable to avoid this error:

```
catch(e : unknown) {
const u = e as YourType
// your logic
}
```

You can still use `any` there, but it's not recommended.

Comment: I make Type and apply it, and get this error `Catch clause variable type annotation must be 'any' or 'unknown' if specified.ts(1196)`

Comment: apologies, let me correct that

Comment: unfortunately, It still same ts error(`Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)`
). I make type like this `type MyError = { code: string }`, then apply your logic `catch (err : unknown)` then `err = err as MyError`

Comment: edited the answer by reassigning the variable, works on my machine

Comment: Yeah me also now works, Thnks for your replay

Answer (score 8):

As stated in other answers, since TypeScript 4.4, errors are automatically cast as unknown, so you can't do anything with them without type checking. Unfortunately ErrnoExceptions are not implemented as an importable class, but rather just a regular Error with additional properties plugged in. It is a type interface in @types/node, but you can't use `isinstance` to check against it since there's no class definition for this exact error, so checking `isinstance` against `Error` will not let you access the `err.code` property. That being said, you can make the compiler happy with:

## OK method

```js
try {
  await fs.readFile(file);
catch (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException) {
  if (err?.code === 'ENOENT') return;
  else throw err;
}
```

The caveat here is if you simply do `if (err.code)...` and forget the `?`, the compiler won't complain, but you could potentially get a runtime error. This is highly unlikely unless err is null/undefined, but it's still not perfectly type safe since you could forget the `?` and get runtime errors in theory. The issue here is you're telling the compiler you know what the error is when in fact the error could be literally anything (which is the motivation to automatically cast errors as unknown).

You could also do `catch (err: any)` but you won't get any type hints for the codes and you are still subject to the same issues if you forget the use the safe accessor on the `code` property. There's not a particularly easy way around this since you cannot simply use safe accessor on `unknown` types like this: `if (err?.code === 'ENOENT') return;`. I'm not quite sure why and maybe they'll add this in a later realease, but either way, my favorite way to handle these fs errors is to write a typeguard helper function like so:

## BEST method

```js
function isErrnoException(e: unknown): e is NodeJS.ErrnoException {
  if ('code' in (e as any)) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

And then your catch block like this:

```js
try {
  await fs.readFile(file);
} catch (err) {
  // writing err.code here after the typeguard call satisfies the compiler and is SAFE because we already checked the member exists in the guard function.
  if (isErrnoException(err) && err.code === 'ENOENT') return;
  else throw err;
}
```

This checks at least the error object is ErrnoException-like in that it has a `code` property. You could get more specific and test that ALL of the ErrnoException properties exist to really make sure it's an ErrnoException.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript/TypeScript you can throw anything, not only errors. In theory it could be anything in the catch block. If you want to prevent the type error it could make sense to check if the `unknown` value is a system error before checking the code.

```
if (err instanceof SystemError && err.code === 'ENOENT') {
  // file not found
}
```

Comment: How can I import SystemError type? I get error `Cannot find name 'SystemError'.ts(2304)`

Answer (score 0):

cast using `Record<string, unknown>` for the type that you don't know about... so it will be:

`const mysteryObject = (unknownObject as Record<string, unknown>)`

this message below really helped me and resolved the issue also:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

in typescript
you can add err : any
ex:

```
 runInitValidation(_bean: any, _oldVal: any, newVal: any) {
const { validators } = this.props;
if (!validators) return;
try {
  for (let i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
    validators[i].validate(newVal);
  }
} catch (err: any) {
  this.errorMessage = err.message;
}
```

}